# How to disable Webview2 auto navigation On Failure?

Tags: c#, webview2

As a normal browser behavior, webview2 will try to navigate to the URL of the last failed navigation attempt.

How can I disable auto navigation?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps you perform and the issue you hit? I'm not sure when the webview2 will attempt to navigate to the URL of the last failed navigation attempt. If you mean you want to stop WebView2 from showing a built-in error page on navigation error you can disable that behavior with `CoreWebView2.Settings.IsBuiltInErrorPageEnabled = false;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2settings?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1418.22#isbuiltinerrorpageenabled

Comment: Thank you. By default, after every several seconds webview2 will try to navigate to last Uri that failed to open either due to wrong URI or no internet connection. It will try that until successful navigation. Try it, you will see that Navigation Completed Event will fire automatically on failed attempt every several seconds.